# How to fix cannot convert system.object[] error

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am receiving the following error when running this script:

> Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 
>   'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 
>   'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.

Also, the users move from the Win7 group to the Win10 group, but depending on if they are members of the other groups in the if statements, none of the groups in the if statements are moving for any of the users. Please help.

Just for reference the userlist file contains Active Directory usernames in a text file like this:

```
jsmith
ksmith
etc.
```

The grouplist text file contains Active Directory groups like this:

```
Nitro7
Project7
Visio7
Zoom7
SnagIt7
OneNote7
```

Code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Get-Content -Path .\userlist.txt
$group = Get-Content -Path .\grouplist.txt
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive


foreach ($user in $users){
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Win7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Win10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose

If ($members.SamAccountName -contains $user) {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Nitro7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Nitro10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($members.SamAccountName -contains $user) {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Project7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Project10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($members.SamAccountName -contains $user) {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "OneNote7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "OneNote10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($members.SamAccountName -contains $user) {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Zoom7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Zoom10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($members.SamAccountName -contains $user) {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "SnagIt7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "SnagIt10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($members.SamAccountName -contains $user) {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Visio7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Visio10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}
}
```

Comment: What does $members look like? It looks like $members should be something like...$members = foreach ($g in $groups) {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.someproperty}

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? $members is just a variable as defined in the very top of the script.

Comment: i think `m0lochwalker` is asking what is the structure of the content of that $Var. you call the code for it with a COLLECTION of groups ... the docs say `[-Identity] <ADGroup>` ... and that parameter value is ONE group, not a _collection of groups_.

Comment: Lee, am I not using grouplist.txt correctly for the collection of groups?

Comment: @Jeff - to get your msg to a particular person, use `@` and their name as it appears when you do that. [*grin*] ///// yes, you are using the cmdlet _incorrectly_ as `m0lochwalker` points out ... you use a collection where the docs clearly state that you MUST have one item. the example code posted by `m0lochwalker` looks like it would work work when  adjusted to fit your data source file.

Comment: @Jeff so, $members isn’t just a variable...it is the output of your cmdlet to which you are assigning to $members. Later in your post you are using $members.SamAccountName. Does $members[0] give you a collection of properties for that object, one of them being SamAccountName?

Comment: Something like $members = $group | foreach-object {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_} could also suit you.

Comment: You are also using the same IF condition over and over. May as well just do every remove/add no matter what, since your condition never changes. Looks like you should rethink a lot of the script. I can help when I’m not in mobile.

Comment: @m0lochwalker, if you could help me come up with a logic that would work for my goal, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @m0lochwalker I mean I know one way would be just to have one if statement and run the script numerous times, changing the group name with the group name hard coded, but that’s what I am trying to prevent having to do.

Comment: @Jeff I provided an answer below. Be very sure you test on a small control group first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `-Identity` property of `Get-ADGroupMember` is [a singleton, not an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps).

However, the `-Identity` property does accept the pipeline for input. So, you may be able to do something like this:

```
$members = $group | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive
```

Although, IMX, some of the AD commands are a bit wonky due to their age. I expect you may need to do something like this:

```
$members = foreach ($g in $group) { Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $g -Recursive }
```

The rest of your script has kind of a confused logic, however, so I can't really tell what you're intending to do.

*{snip}*

---

Based on your comments, here's what I'd do.

First, I'd change your groups file. Instead of a plain text list of the groups, I'd make it a CSV file with two columns: The old group and the new group.

So, `grouplist.csv` looks like this:

```
"OldGroupName","NewGroupName"
"Nitro7","Nitro10"
"OneNote7","OneNote10"
"Project7","Project10"
"SnagIt7","SnagIt10"
"Visio7","Visio10"
"Win7","Win10"
"Zoom7","Zoom10"
```

Now you have a map for each old group and the group you want to migrate your users to.

Now, we do it like this:

```
$users = Get-Content .\userlist.txt
$groups = Import-Csv .\grouplist.csv

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $UsersToModify = Get-ADGroupMember $group.OldGroupName -Recursive | Where-Object SamAccountName -in $users
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.OldGroupName -Members $UsersToModify -Confirm:$false -Verbose -WhatIf
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.NewGroupName -Members $UsersToModify -Confirm:$false -Verbose -WhatIf
}
```

*[Note: Remove the `-WhatIf` to actually perform the actions.]*

For each group, we get a list of the groups members, filter it to the usernames in `$users` and save that to `$UsersToModify`. Then, we pass that list of users to the Remove and Add commands. We only need to call it once per each group.

I know you had a special exception for Win7 to Win10, but I don't see where the logic of the script really needs to change to accommodate that. If you want to always add all users in `$users` to Win10, you could add that manually:

```
$UsersToAddtoWin10 = $users | Get-ADUser
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Win10 -Members $UsersToAddtoWin10 -Confirm:$false -Verbose -WhatIf
```

Comment: I only want to remove the user from the “7” groups and add them to the new “10” groups if and only if they are a member of the “7” group. For example, if the user is only a member of Nitro7, I only want the user to be removed from Nitro7 and added to Nitro 10, but not added to any other “10” groups.  If the user is a member of 3 of the 6  “7” groups, I only want them to be removed from those 3 “7” groups and added to the corresponding “10” groups. Am I close?

Comment: I also want the user to move from Win7 to Win10 regardless, that’s why I didn’t put that portion in an if statement.

Comment: How would I remove the "7" group and add only the corresponding "10" group if the user is only a member of a couple of these groups?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this will work for you, considering your $user and $group lists are exactly as you show...

```
#get your users...

$users = Get-Content -Path .\userlist.txt

#get your groups...

$groups = Get-Content -Path .\grouplist.txt

#for each user...

foreach ($user in $users) {

    #get their group memberships, expand the property...

    $memberOf = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberof

    #for each membership found in $groups that also ends in '7'...

    foreach ($membership in ($memberOf | Where-Object {($_ -match ($groups -join "|")) -and ($_ -like '*7')})) {

        #remove the user from the matched group...

        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $membership -Members $user -Confirm:$false

        #add the user to a group with the same name, replacing 7 with 10...

        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $membership.Replace("7","10") -Members $user -Confirm:$false

    }

}
```

**IMPORTANT**

Please note that this ***-match*** operator will return any other groups that are contained in ***$groups*** that also end in ***7***. If you have additional group names that match that criteria stored in ***$groups***, you will want more filtering on ***$memberOf*** for the ***$membership*** iteration.

This script will also replace every instance of the character '7' in $membership (a matched group's DistinguishedName), with '10', in order to add $user to the new group. So, make sure that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Get-Content -Path .\userlist.txt

foreach ($user in $users){

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "View_Win7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "View_Win10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose

[array]$grps=Get-ADUser $user -Property memberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select Name

foreach($grp in $grps){

if($grp.Name -match "Nitro7") {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Nitro7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Nitro10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($grp.Name -match "Project7") {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Project7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Project10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($grp.Name -match "OneNote7") {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "OneNote7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "OneNote10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($grp.Name -match "Zoom7") {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Zoom7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Zoom10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($grp.Name -match "SnagIt7") {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "SnagIt7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "SnagIt10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}

If ($grp.Name -match "Visio7") {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Visio7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Visio10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}
}
}
```

Comment: I solved it with this code. Any easier way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Yes, review my answer. You got on the right track by getting the MemberOf property for each user, which is what I did in my answer. If your $groups list contains only the groups you are removing from, then my code has no risk and would work great. Glad it's working.

Comment: Thank you @m0lochwalker

Comment: If you have any questions about that script, just let me know.